# expect not working well with banner messages

Tags: expect

I'm using expect-lite to communicate with a router. however the router has some customized banner message set and expect doesn't seem to work very well with it. Specifically, when I login in to the router, the cursor was placed at the following location.

```
***********************************************
*                                             *
*            some unuseful info here..        *
*                                             *
***********************************************($cursor)
```

normally I can just hit enter in an interactive shell and it can then bring me to the normal router shell, I have expected "*" and then send a new line character, but it doesn't seem to work well.

Can you shed some light on this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is add `exp_internal 1` somewhere at the beginning of your script, and that way you can see what expect is receiving, and why it is not matching your pattern.

Feel free to add that information to the question if you need some help with interpreting what you get from it.

Answer (score 0):

with the default options to `expect` ("glob" patterns, documented [here](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M39)), `*` is a wildcard and will match anything (including nothing). Make sure you're expecting a literal asterisk:

```
expect -re {\*$}
```

Here I'm using a regular expression to find an asterisk anchored at the end of the string.

Comment: thanks, i got it working now with expect. although it still doesn't work for expect-lite if you have heard of. thanks for the input